# git workflow for public feature branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

**Our Workflow:**

We have a develop branch where all the new features and fixes are pushed. We cut a release_candidate branch from develop branch which then goes into master upon release.

For individual features and fixes, each developer creates a feature branch. We have git configured to default to git pull --rebase. Each feature branch is generally a local branch that we rebase often from develop. This keeps a nice clean commit history, simple to merge back into develop and we can easily submit the changes in feature branch for review as a patch. As far as local feature branches go this flow is ideal. It causes minimum fuss, results in a clean commit history and allows us to squash commits when merging into develop.

**Problem:**

The problem arose when we had a couple of long lasting feature branches which were pushed to remote for backup and collaboration. However, frequent rebasing the remote feature branch was a disaster (because of our own lack of understanding of how rebase works). We have since learned not to rebase public feature branches.

**Question:**

What would be a clean git workflow for remote feature branches? We need to maintain the ability to bring in changes from develop while continuing work on the feature branch as it could contain pertinent fixes. We would also like to keep clean commit history and ability to review (we use arc) the feature branch as a patch that can be fast-forwarded onto develop.

There can be multiple long running public feature branches and each feature branch can have multiple developers working in parallel

The idea of pull requests is not very appealing. We already use arc for code review and would not like to appoint a point person responsible for reviewing pull requests.

**Relevant Reads:**

- https://randyfay.com/node/89
- https://randyfay.com/node/91
- https://randyfay.com/node/103

Comment: What were your disastrous problems rebase pulling public feature branches? This generally works fine, sometimes you want to fetch and diff first before interactive rebase to resolve conflicts.

Comment: There were conflicts in one of the commits in the rebase and I ended up fixing that conflict for every subsequent commit in the rebase and because I did not realize the underlying problem, I ended up doing the same more than once. The underlying problem being that rebasing a remote feature branch causes commit history to be rewritten and I wasted 2 days fixing the 190 commit conflicts manually

Comment: Sounds like you were missing [`rerere`](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html)

Comment: That's a very interesting feature! Thanks for sharing. However it does not resolve the underlying issue that rebase rewrites commit history and that will cause problems for other developers when one of us rebases. The consensus exists that rebasing a remote feature branch is a bad idea. The question remains what do we do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Upon reading your post, to me it seems there's nothing wrong with your branching (at least). There's also nothing wrong with your rebase workflow. However I would suggest to only rebase the feature branches ONLY when it's time to merge them back to develop-branch. So while in collaboration, no one will experience the horror of having to fix their local repo to start the day. Now a drawback is that when feature branches are hanging in there for weeks. You will end up with a code not updated and will spend probably a day or two to test and just fix conflicts, in which case i suggest also to squash the commits in feature-branch so fixing conflicts will be a lot easier.

Next, since my first suggestion has limits, I would suggest making an exception for those long-living branches and just update them from develop from time-to-time. You may/will not have the same desired outcome for your revision history but I think it will be more of the gain weighs more than the loss.

```
develop     o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o
             \                   \           \         /
feature       mike---betty--paul--o--bt-mk-mk-o---bt--pl
```

Comment: Completely agree with you. This is the way we ended up doing it as well. Rebasing is tricky and not every one seems to understand it completely so to avoid disasters, we now do a longer running feature branch with smaller sub task branches that we can PR into the feature branch. We pull develop periodically into feature branch to stay up to date and then always just before submitting the final PR so that the merge onto develop is a fast forward. This seems to give the optimal balance between clean history and ease of development